# XQuery function to use to connect and copy documents from one database to another in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

What xquery functions I can use to connect with a MarkLogic database and copy the collection from that database to another database located in the same MarkLogic server.

Comment: When you say "copy the collection", you mean copy all of the documents in that collection, right? You want to find all of the documents in a particular collection and copy them to a different database?

Comment: Yes thats right. Copying all documents in one collection from a source database to the other database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`xdmp:invoke-function()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:invoke-function) and specify a different `database` in the options.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $doc in cts:search(doc(), cts:collection-query("collection-name"))
let $uri := $doc/base-uri()
let $collections := xdmp:document-get-permissions($uri)
let $permissions := xdmp:document-get-collections($uri)
return
  xdmp:invoke-function(function() { 
      xdmp:document-insert($uri, $doc, $permissions, $collections) 
    },
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
      <database>{ xdmp:database("GTM2_TEST") }</database>
    </options>)
```

If you have a really large number of documents in the collection, then you might want to look at either [`xdmp:spawn-function()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:spawn-function), or doing the work with a batch tool, such as [CoRB](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2) to avoid Expanded Tree Cache errors and/or timeouts from an attempt to process them all in one giant transaction.

Comment: xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $doc in cts:search(doc(), cts:collection-query("GTM2_Shipment"))
let $uri := $doc/base-uri()
let $db-name := "GTM2_FINAL"
return
  xdmp:invoke-function(function() { 
      xdmp:document-insert($uri, $doc) 
    },
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
      <database>xdmp:database("$db-name")</database>
    </options>);


I am using this , but it reports :
Invalid option value: option '/*:options/*:database' has unexpected value 'xdmp:database("GTM2_TEST")

I am executing this in one DB and trying to insert document in GTM2_TEST DB. Can you please help.

Comment: It needs the ID of the database. You need to wrap the call to xdmp:database with curly braces, to create a code block to execute and return the ID. Right now the function call is being sent as a literal string.

Comment: I have tried both these and it gaves me same invalid option error - 
<database>xdmp:database{"GTM2_TEST"}</database>
<database>xdmp:database("GTM2_TEST")</database>
<database>xdmp:database(GTM2_TEST)</database>

Missing Context item when I used 
<database>xdmp:database{GTM2_TEST}</database>

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear. The curly braces need to wrap around the function call: `<database>{ xdmp:database("GTM2_TEST") }</database>`.  I updated the answer to include it with the enclosed expression.

Comment: It work with the above syntax. However the collection and permission things doesnot gets copied. I am trying this code- |

Comment: I will open a new question for this issue, thanks .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72803218/18123235 

@MadsHansen - Can you please check if possible.