# Copy documents from one database to another in MarkLogic - xdmp:document-insert Failing

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am using the below code to copy documents from one database to another database in MarkLogic.
But I am getting error - arg2 is not of type node()
The xquery I am trying -

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $doc in cts:search(doc(), cts:collection-query('Shipment'))
let $docuri := $doc/base-uri()
let $collections := xdmp:document-get-collections($docuri)
let $permissions := xdmp:document-get-permissions($docuri)
let $db-name := "GTM2_FINAL"
return
 xdmp:invoke-function(function()
  {
  xdmp:document-insert
  (
  $docuri, $docuri,
  <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert" xmlns1="xdmp:eval">  
      <permissions>{xdmp:default-permissions()}</permissions>
      <collections>
           {
       <collection>GTM2_Shipment</collection>,
       <collection>Shipment</collection>
           }
        </collections>
      <database>{ xdmp:database("GTM2_TEST") }</database>
      <commit>auto</commit>
    </options>
    )
    }
    );
```

Here is the error I am getting -

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) xdmp:document-insert(xs:anyURI("/shipment/test..."), xs:anyURI("/shipment/test..."), <options xmlns1="xdmp:eval" xmlns="xdmp:document-insert"><permissions>...</permissions>...</options>) -- arg2 is not of type node()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues with your code, but the first one and what the error message is telling you, is that the second parameter for `xdmp:document-insert()` is not a node. You specified `$docuri`, which is a string value of the URI of the document. The second parameter should instead be `$doc`.

The other issue I see is that you have mixed the parameters for the `xdmp:document-insert()` function with the options parameter for the `xdmp:invoke-function()`. Two different options params need to be specified, and the elements are bound to two different namespaces.

The options parameter for the `xdmp:document-insert()` should be:

```
<options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">  
    <permissions>{xdmp:default-permissions()}</permissions>
    <collections>
      <collection>GTM2_Shipment</collection>
      <collection>Shipment</collection>
    </collections> 
</options>
```

Or if you want to use the permissions and collections of the document:

```
<options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">  
    <permissions>{$permissions}</permissions>
  <collections>{$collections}</collections> 
</options>
```

The options parameter for the `xdmp:invoke-function()` are:

```
<options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
  <database>{ xdmp:database("GTM2_TEST") }</database>
  <commit>auto</commit>
</options>
```

And if you don't want to use the collections or permissions from the document, then no need to fetch them. The answer that I provided in previous answers showed a way to use them with the older API for `xdmp:document-insert()` that used collections and permissions as specific parameters, rather than within the options parameter.

You let a variable `$db-name` with the value "GTM2_FINAL", but don't use it and instead have hard-coded the value in the eval option. Either use the variable instead of the string, or get rid of the unused variable.

Applying the changes:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $doc in cts:search(doc(), cts:collection-query('Shipment'))
let $docuri := $doc/base-uri()
let $collections := xdmp:document-get-collections($docuri)
let $permissions := xdmp:document-get-permissions($docuri)
let $db-name := "GTM2_FINAL"
return
 xdmp:invoke-function(function()
  {
    xdmp:document-insert(
      $docuri, $doc,
      <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">  
        <permissions>{$permissions}</permissions>
        <collections>{$collections}</collections> 
      </options>
    )
   },
   <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
      <database>{ xdmp:database($db-name) }</database>
      <commit>auto</commit>
   </options>
 );
```

If it makes it easier, you could also `let` named variables for the options, to make it easier to read and keep the actual function calls shorter:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $doc in cts:search(doc(), cts:collection-query('Shipment'))
let $docuri := $doc/base-uri()
let $collections := xdmp:document-get-collections($docuri)
let $permissions := xdmp:document-get-permissions($docuri)
let $document-insert-options := 
  <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">  
    <permissions>{$permissions}</permissions>
    <collections>{$collections}</collections> 
  </options>
let $db-name := "GTM2_FINAL"  
let $invoke-function-options := 
  <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
    <database>{ xdmp:database($db-name) }</database>
    <commit>auto</commit>
  </options>
return
 xdmp:invoke-function(
   function(){ xdmp:document-insert($docuri, $doc, $document-insert-options)},
   $invoke-function-options
 );
```